# System goes unstable doesn't even working from live USB

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, filesystem, system, usb-installation

2 days back my system goes completely unstable when I remove bunsenlabs as it does not sporting my wifi USB adapter. So I try to install Ubuntu and now lubuntu but my system is not responding. When I try to boot it from live USB it shows some processor errors and after booting installation in not going further than 2nd page. Gparted not working either, first it opens and crashes and now it's keep on loading but nothing happening. I think it's maybe because I change the harddisk from an old 160gb Seagate barracuda to WD blue 1tb as the 160gb is dying so I think I need to save the data before it's gone. My CPU is really old one it's Pentium 4 processor with newly baught 2 GB ddr2 ram and the newly baught 1tb harddisk and one more thing guys even my old harddisk is about to die but it is still working good with the system system booting normally just showing some checkdisk error of corrupted file system but main thing is system works when I use old hdd but it doesn't when I use the new one. So please give me some advice help me coming through this problem this is my learning system it helps me learn and build stable web development skill and I don't want to lose it like this.
I'm attaching 2 pics below one is when system boots and the other one is when I try to install lubuntu and it stuck on 2 page of installation.
Sorry I cannot post i.ages as my reputation is not ten

https://ibb.co/ctLpmG

https://ibb.co/kzuX6G

Comment: You can [edit] your post and paste links to the images on imgur or another image sharing site. ALso, it sounds like perhaps there are some hardware issues with your computer.

Comment: It would indeed seem you have some serious hardware problems there. Unfortunately we can't really help you with that on here. If you don't know enough to resolve the issue yourself, you'd probably be best finding a good local repair shop to have a look.